# Changing the contents of a pointer variable

Tags: c++, pointers

In this code:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
const char* name = "Abc";
std::cout<<*name<<std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

How can I change the contents of the pointer variable, **not** to what it is pointing at?

And, why am I just getting `A` as output from this program?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You get a `char` because you are de-referencing a `char*` pointer.

You could change the contents by doing:

```
*a = 'B'; // your char* would contain "Bbc"
a[0] = 'B'; // your char* would contain "Bbc"
a[1] = 'B'; // your char* would contain "ABc"
a[2] = 'B'; // your char* would contain "AbB"
```

But, changing the contents of a string literal has an **undefined** behavior in **C**. So you should not do that. Instead, you need to populate your `char*` dynamically. With something like this:

```
char *a;
a = malloc(sizeof(char)*100); // a string with a maximum of 99 chars
strcpy(a, "Abc");
// now you can safely change char* contents:
a[0] = '1';
a[1] = '1';
a[2] = '1';
printf("%s", a); // will print 111
```

String manipulation is not that easy in languages like **C**. Since by the syntax you are using, you seem to be compiling your code with a **C++** compiler, then you might give `string` class a try instead of using pointers to `char` to handle your strings.

Answer (score 4):

**You shouldn't try and change the contents of a const char* variable.** By definition it is constant. If you want a mutable string, use std::string, or allocate a char* buffer[] instead.

Answer (score 1):

YOu are accessing `*Name` which refers to first location in memory which has A
I fyou want B print `*(Name+1)` and etc..

If you want to change the content then assign the value to *Name or *(Name+1) or where ever you want.

Comment: Be warned: changing string literals is undefined behaviour - they are const for a very good reason

Answer (score 1):

to change the address value of `name` you can change to the address of another string literal:

```
const char* newname = "def";
name = newname;
```

such that name is still a pointer to const char.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand const with regards to pointers.

const char * means a pointer to data that you cannot modify, but you can move the pointer.

```
const char * name = "Abc";
name = "Def"; // allowed
name[1]='B'; // compiler error
```

If you want a pointer you cannot move then use

```
 const char * const name = "Abc"; // cannot move to point at something else
 char data[] = "ghi";
 char * const name = &data[0]; 
 name[1] = 'H'; // permitted
 name = &data[1]; // not allowed as name is a constant pointer
```

Your output is A because *name is a char, the one your pointer points to, thus the first one in the string.